# Initialise external PHP file - JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a div with id `trigger` in my page. I have a php file `action.php` which will delete contents in my text file `mytext.txt`. I want to do that when I click `trigger` using jQuery. Or is there any function to do that without PHP file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a click handler to your DIV. It's actually better if you had a link instead, but not essential (i.e. - html5)

```
$('#trigger').click(function(){
   $.get('action.php', {}, function(data){ //populate {} if you want to send any data
      alert(data);//whatever your action.php file echoes out.
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `$.ajax`, you can call your PHP script from Javascript.. You can't access neither client-side nor server-side files (such as `mytext.txt`) from javascript.